# Plot values returned by command output

Tags: linux, cpu, gnuplot

I have a little script that prints the CPU temperature after each **T** period of time, so the output is something like this:

```
19/02/15,01:00
30
19/02/15,02:00
33
19/02/15,03:00
38
19/02/15,04:00
32
```

and so on (that one refreshes every hour, as you can see).

How can I plot the respective values? Maybe using gnuplot?
To give an idea, I am interested in 2D orthogonal plot, where the horizontal axis (Ox) represents time and the vertical axis (Oy) represents the temperature.

I can save those values in a file, that is, `./temp_show > out` and use that `out` file as an input for a graphing software.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has worked for me in the past for live and continuous plotting: http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/gnuplotStreaming.html

Comment: There are a ton of options. R is an obvious one. See also http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10320/285 and http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1095/285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you had arranged your script output in columns; however at its most basic you could do something like

```
paste - - < out | nl | 
  gnuplot -p -e 'plot "-" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes title "my data"'
```

[image: Gnuplot screenshot]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you, good sir!